# Hilbert polynomial, degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry

my question concerns the Hilbertpolynomial of a coherent sheaf $F$ on a smooth projective variety $X$ with canonical bundle $\omega_X$: does the Hilbertpolynomial always have degree equal to $dim supp(F)$ or does in general only an inequality hold?
And is there a connection to ampleness of the canonical sheaf resp. its dual?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the degree of the Hilbert polynomial of a coherent sheaf $F$ on a projective variety $X$  over a field $K$  is equal to the dimension of the support of $F$.
This  is true even if  $X$ is not smooth and has nothing to do with the canonical sheaf of $X$.
Beware however that the actual Hilbert polynomial *does* depend on the projective embeddding of $X$ in projective space, even if its degree is independent of the embedding.
You can check this by calculating the Hilbert polynomials of the structural sheaf $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_K}$ of the projective line and that of the structural sheaf $\mathcal O_{C}$ of a smooth plane conic $C\subset \mathbb P^2_K$.

And I'll give you the most splendid reference: it is the very last result in Serre's FAC! (one of the most important papers ever published in Mathematics)
More precisely it is Proposition 6, § 81, page 276 in Serre, [*Faisceaux Algébriques Cohérents*](http://www.mat.uniroma1.it/people/arbarello/FAC.pdf).
There is an English translation  [here](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pta/fac/fac.pdf)  (as I learned from [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14404/serres-fac-in-english))

Comment: Great answer, Georges! Thank you very much!